# Split a string according to tags and text with regex

Tags: javascript, string, parsing, tags

##### I need to parse a string, which contains both text content and specific tags.

Expected result must be an array containing items, with separation between texts and tags.

### An example of string to parse

```
There is user [[user-foo]][[/user-foo]] and user [[user-bar]]label[[/user-bar]].
```

Some informations:

- `user-` tag is static.
- Following part (`foo` or `bar`) is dynamic and can be any string.
- Same for the text parts.
- Tags can receive some text as child.

### Expected result

```
[
  'There is user ',
  '[[user-foo]][[/user-foo]]',
  ' and user ',
  '[[user-bar]]label[[/user-bar]]',
  '.'
]
```

### What I tried

Here is a regex I created:

```
/\[\[user-[^\]]+]][A-Za-z]*\[\[\/user-[^\]]+\]\]/g
```

It's visible/editable here: https://regex101.com/r/ufwVV1/1

It identifies all tag parts, and returns two matches, related to the two tags I have. But, text content is not included. I don't know if this first approach is correct.

Comment: If the sub strings 'There is user' and 'and user' are static and common in every case, then you could just split the entire string using these. You can even store it directly as array.

Comment: No, they are not static. All is dynamic, except the fact that tags always start with `user-`.

Comment: `I tried to use some regex` this might work, let’s see what you tried.

Comment: @James I just added some informations about what I tried.

Comment: Looks ok just needs some capture groups to extract 1.  The tag name and 2. The value. https://regex101.com/r/FS1xzu/1

Comment: Thanks for your example. It's not what I want, as it does not include text content (look at the expected array I need).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there's a better solution in terms of efficiency... But at least, that works.

1. Get the tags using regex
2. Get the tags position (start/end) within the string
3. Use those positions against the string

```js
const string = "There is user [[user-foo]][[/user-foo]] and user [[user-bar]]label[[/user-bar]]."

// Get the tags using regex
const matches = string.match(/\[\[[a-z-\/]+\]\]/g)
console.log(matches)

// Get the tags position (start/end) within the string
const matchPositions = matches.map((match) => ({start: string.indexOf(match), end: string.indexOf(match) + match.length}))
console.log(matchPositions)

// Use those positions against the string
let currentPos = 0
let result = []
for(let i=0; i<matchPositions.length; i+=2){
  const position = matchPositions[i]
  const secondPosition  = matchPositions[i+1]
  
  // Get the substring in front of the current tag (if any)
  if(position.start !== currentPos){
    const firstSubString = string.slice(currentPos, position.start)
    if(firstSubString !== ""){
      result.push(firstSubString)
    }
  }
  
  // Get the substring from the opening tag start to the closing tag end
  result.push(string.slice(position.start, secondPosition.end))
  currentPos = secondPosition.end
  
  // Get the substring at the end of the string (if any)
  if(i === matchPositions.length-2){
    const lastSubString = string.slice(secondPosition.end)
    if(lastSubString !== ""){
      result.push(lastSubString)
    }
    
  }
}

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It inspired me to post my solution. Just a comment:
we don't need to use `indexOf` to get the index of each match : you have access to `index` property on each one.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution, inspired from [@louys-patrice-bessette](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2159528/louys-patrice-bessette) answer.

```js
const string = 'There is user [[user-foo]][[/user-foo]] and user [[user-bar]]label[[/user-bar]].';
const regex = /\[\[user-[^\]]+\]\][A-Za-z0-9_ ]*\[\[\/user-[^\]]+\]\]/g;

const { index, items } = [...string.matchAll(regex)].reduce(
    (result, regExpMatchArray) => {
      const [match] = regExpMatchArray;
      const { index: currentIndex } = regExpMatchArray;

      if (currentIndex === undefined) {
        return result;
      }

      return {
        items: [
          ...result.items,
          string.substring(result.index, currentIndex),
          match,
        ],
        index: currentIndex + match.length,
      };
    },
    {
      index: 0,
      items: [],
    }
  );

if (index !== string.length) {
  items.push(string.substring(index, string.length));
}

console.log(items);
```

Comment: Glad that I inspired you on this very different solution ;)